# Return two shortcodes with one function [Wordpress PHP]

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am attempting to merge the following two functions into one, which are completely identical other than the $utmphone and $utmphonedirect

```
// UTM Change Toll Free Phone
 add_action( 'wp_head', 'toll_phone' );
function toll_phone() { 
$utmphone = '<a class="whitehref" href="tel:8004806850">800-480-6850</a>';
if(isset($_COOKIE['utm']) && $_COOKIE['utm']== "ccov" || (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "ccov"))) { 
$utmphone = '<a class="whitehref" href="tel:8004484285">(800) 448-4285</a>'; 
setcookie('utm', 'ccov', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
return $utmphone;
}
add_shortcode('utmphone', 'toll_phone');  

// UTM Change Direct Phone
function direct_phone() { 
$utmphonedirect = '<a href="tel:312-666-3552">312-666-3552</a>';
if(isset($_COOKIE['utm']) && $_COOKIE['utm']== "ccov" || (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "ccov"))) { 
$utmphonedirect = '<a href="tel:8722604892">(872) 260-4892</a>';
}
return $utmphonedirect;
}
add_shortcode('utmphonedirect', 'direct_phone');
```

I have tried the following, but it is only returning one of the values - therefore both shortcodes are displaying the same. I have also searched the web for a simple answer for something like this and found nothing.

The goal is to output two unique values for both shortcodes: utmphone and utmphonedirect

```
// UTM Change BOTH Phones
 add_action( 'wp_head', 'toll_phone' );
function toll_phone() { 
$utmphone = '<a class="whitehref" href="tel:8004806850">800-480-6850</a>';
$utmphonedirect = '<a href="tel:312-666-3552">312-666-3552</a>';
if(isset($_COOKIE['utm']) && $_COOKIE['utm']== "ccov" || (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "ccov"))) { 
$utmphone = '<a class="whitehref" href="tel:8004484285">(800) 448-4285</a>'; 
$utmphonedirect = '<a href="tel:8722604892">(872) 260-4892</a>';
setcookie('utm', 'ccov', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
return $utmphone;
return $utmphonedirect;
}
add_shortcode('utmphone', 'toll_phone');  
add_shortcode('utmphonedirect', 'direct_phone');
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
// UTM Change Toll Free Phone
function toll_phone()
{
    $utmphone = '<a class="whitehref" href="tel:8004806850">800-480-6850</a>';

    if (isset($_COOKIE['utm']) && $_COOKIE['utm'] == "ccov" || (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "ccov"))) {
        $utmphone = '<a class="whitehref" href="tel:8004484285">(800) 448-4285</a>';
        setcookie('utm', 'ccov', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    }

    return $utmphone;
}
add_shortcode('utmphone', 'toll_phone');

// UTM Change Direct Phone
function direct_phone()
{
    $utmphonedirect = '<a href="tel:312-666-3552">312-666-3552</a>';

    if (isset($_COOKIE['utm']) && $_COOKIE['utm'] == "ccov" || (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "ccov"))) {
        $utmphonedirect = '<a href="tel:8722604892">(872) 260-4892</a>';
    }

    return $utmphonedirect;
}
add_shortcode('utmphonedirect', 'direct_phone');
```

Usage

```
[utmphone]
[utmphonedirect]
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, but am actually attempting to create two entirely unique shortcodes. 1 for utmphone and 1 for utmphonedirect

Comment: you need to clarify your question then.

Comment: Apologies, I have just updated the question